# Do eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix depend smoonthly on its entries?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, perturbation-theory, symmetric-matrices

Let's consider the following maps:
$$\Lambda_i:S\to\Bbb R, \quad A\mapsto \Lambda_i(A),\quad i=1,\cdots,n$$
where $S$ is the vector space of all $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices under the Frobenius norm and $\Lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$-th greatest eigenvalue of $A$ (since all eigenvalues of $A$ are real this map is obviously well defined). Given any matrix $A\in S$, does there always exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\Lambda_i$ is smooth on $B_\epsilon(A)$? In the event of distinct eigenvalues, the answer is yes as a direct corollary from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299990/64010). But what about general $A$ i.e. not necessarily with distinct eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can already check that this isn't true for diagonal matrices. Consider, for example, the smooth path

$$M(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} t & 0 \\ 0 & -t \end{array} \right]$$

through $S$, where $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. The eigenvalues of this matrix, in order of size, are $|t|$ and $-|t|$, so neither $\Lambda_1(M(t))$ nor $\Lambda_2(M(t))$ are smooth at $t = 0$, where the two eigenvalues of $M(t)$ collide.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this one coming.

Comment: This counterexample suggests a follow-up question, which is whether there exist smooth functions $\Lambda_i$ such that $(\Lambda_1, \dots \Lambda_n)$ are the eigenvalues in some order, not necessarily from greatest to least. The answer to this should also be no, I think, and one should be able to exhibit a more complicated path that shows why although I don't know an example off the top of my head.

Comment: Then is it at least *continuous*? I suspect yes although in this case the analytic tools like implicit function theorem might not be applicable

Comment: @Vim: yes, they're even Lipschitz with respect to the operator norm with Lipschitz constant $1$. See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/.

Comment: how can we define such an "in some order" map?